# File globbing without word splitting?

Tags: bash, shell, glob

This is a simplified example to hopefully illustrate my problem.

I have a script that takes a parameter to be used as a wildcard.  Sometimes this wildcard contains whitespace.  I need to be able to use the wildcard for globbing, but word splitting is causing it to fail.

For example, consider the following example files:

```
$ ls -l "/home/me/dir with whitespace"
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 me     Domain Users 0 Jun 25 16:58 file_a.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me     Domain Users 0 Jun 25 16:58 file_b.txt
```

My script - simplified to use a hard coded pattern variable - looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Here this is hard coded, but normally it would be passed via parameter
# For example: pattern="${1}"
# The whitespace and wildcard can appear anywhere in the pattern
pattern="/home/me/dir with whitespace/file_*.txt"

# First attempt: without quoting
ls -l ${pattern}

# Result: word splitting AND globbing
#   ls: cannot access /home/me/dir: No such file or directory
#   ls: cannot access with: No such file or directory
#   ls: cannot access whitespace/file_*.txt: No such file or directory


####################

# Second attempt: with quoting
ls -l "${pattern}"

# Result: no word splitting, no globbing
#   ls: cannot access /home/me/dir with whitespace/file_*.txt: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to enable globbing, but disable word splitting?
Do I have any options except manually escaping whitespace in my pattern?

Comment: How about non-manually escaping the whitespace?  `pattern="${pattern// /\\ }`.  You'd need to escape other significant characters (e.g. `;`), so I don't recommend this alone!

Comment: Is `"'${pattern//\*/\'*\'}'"` any help?  Single-quote the entire string, then replace `*` with `'*'` to put them back outside the string.  Might need to do the same with `?`, too.

Comment: @TobySpeight - I tried escaping the whitespace.  It still falls victim to word splitting because the `\\` is being taken literally because it's inside a variable.  The second suggestion didn't work either as it's taking the `'` literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it!

The trick is modifying the [internal field separator](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSREF) (`IFS`) to be null.  This prevents word splitting on unquoted variables until `IFS` is reverted to its old value or until it becomes unset.

Example:

```
$ pattern="/home/me/dir with whitespace/file_*.txt"

$ ls -l $pattern
ls: cannot access /home/me/dir: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access with: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access whitespace/file_*.txt: No such file or directory

$ IFS=""
$ ls -l $pattern
-rw-r--r-- 1 me     Domain Users 0 Jun 26 09:14 /home/me/dir with whitespace/file_a.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me     Domain Users 0 Jun 26 09:14 /home/me/dir with whitespace/file_b.txt

$ unset IFS
$ ls -l $pattern
ls: cannot access /home/me/dir: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access with: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access whitespace/file_*.txt: No such file or directory
```

I found out the hard way that you cannot set and use `IFS` with `ls`.  For example, this doesn't work:

```
$ IFS="" ls -l $pattern
```

This is because the command has already undergone word splitting *before* `IFS` changes.

Answer (score 3):

Don't keep glob inside the quote to be able to expand it:

```
pattern="/home/me/dir with whitespace/file_"

ls -l "${pattern}"*
```

---

**EDIT:**

Based on edited question and comment you can use `find`:

```
find . -path "./$pattern" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l
```

Comment: I would, but in the actual script it's being passed as a parameter, not hard coded.  For example, the script is called with `./script.sh "/home/me/dir with whitespace/file_*.txt"` and inside the script it does `pattern="${1}"`.  The whitespace and wildcard can appear anywhere in the parameter and I don't know in advance where they will be.

Comment: ok check updated answer using `find`. Will check back tomorrow morning as it is damn late here.